# QField synchronisation does not work

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync

Recently I started using QField (with QGIS 3.22). The creation of a package and collecting of the data on the mobile devices are working just fine. Points are visible on the map and contain data.

But now I'm trying to synchronise the data with the project on my computer and the synchronisation does not work. I've copied the project from the device to a new folder and used the QField plugin tot add the data to the project.

Also opening the QField package as a project does not give the desired result, nor does using the cloud function.
I've tried everything I could find on the net and even made a new project to try every single possiblity.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, the data is visible in QField but not found in the files. Is there anyone with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the missing files. Apparently QField creates duplicate files and stores them in a different folder on your mobile device. You can find your edited files here: Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\imported projects

I copied them from here to a location on my pc and opened them in QGIS, they are working fine now.

Comment: I found this answer very useful as I have exactly the same issue. It makes sense although is it not in the QField documentation. However, in QGIS 3.28 (Firenze), I did try to use the Plugins -> QFieldSync -> Synchronize from QField and search my copied project folder copied from Android mobile device, it looks to synchronize, but none of my tracks recorded in QField (2.6.3) display correctly (it does on QField on the Android device). Any step I missed?